# RDLC report print button not showing in Mozilla & Chrome

Tags: .net, button, printing, report, rdlc

I have a problem regarding RDLC report. I want to display print button in RDLC report viewer. So for that I have made ShowPrintButton option true in report view. But result is that its working fine in IE but in mozilla & chrome print button is invisible. How can i make that print button visible in all browsers?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The print button doesn't work in Firefox/Chrome because it's an ActiveX control.

You can try this solution (I have not tested it yet):
[ReportViewer print button in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276424/reportviewer-print-button-in-google-chrome)